# How can I theme my Qt app to resemble one written in Gtk?

Tags: development, gtk, qt, application-development

Mark Shuttleworth [recently blogged](http://www.markshuttleworth.com/archives/568) about the decision to include the Qt libraries in the 11.10 release, with a [followup from Jono Bacon](http://www.jonobacon.org/2011/01/18/some-further-notes-on-qt-in-ubuntu/). The thing that puts me off Qt apps is that they don't blend in very well with Ubuntu's Gtk-based theme. I recently read an [Ars Technica article](http://arstechnica.com/open-source/news/2010/10/canonical-cto-contemplates-qt-we-think-it-has-a-lot-to-offer-ubuntu.ars) that mentioned that, with a bit of effort, Qt apps could be make to resemble Gtk apps.

Is there any documentation that will help me do this, and if not, does anyone at least have any idea how one would go about doing this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> *Note: this is useful to desktop users, not to developers using Qt.*

`sudo apt-get install qt4-qtconfig`, then go to *System / Preferences / Qt 4 settings* and select GTK style in the first combobox:

[image: Qt Configuration dialog]

Comment: this is already default since lucid .

Comment: Is there a way to do this that works with GTK3?

Comment: This is great except it does nothing to change the icons that the qt apps use. For example, dolphin uses some really ugly icons running on ubuntu unity

Answer (score 3):

Qt apps  don't follow the font hinting settings that are set by `gnome-appearance-properties`. You need to explicitly add an entry to `$HOME/.fonts.conf` e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
 <match target="font" >
  <edit mode="assign" name="rgba" >
   <const>rgb</const>
  </edit>
 </match>
 <match target="font" >
  <edit mode="assign" name="hinting" >
   <bool>true</bool>
  </edit>
 </match>
 <match target="font" >
  <edit mode="assign" name="hintstyle" >
   <const>hintfull</const>
  </edit>
 </match>
</fontconfig>
```

Answer (score 1):

From nagul's SU post https://superuser.com/questions/37444/how-can-i-make-kde-and-other-non-gnome-apps-inherit-the-ubuntu-theme - direct quote:

> Check
>   [**QGtkStyle**](http://labs.trolltech.com/page/Projects/Styles/GtkStyle),
>   a project to [create a GTK+
>   layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QGtkStyle)
>   for Qt-based applications (like KDE)
>   running on GTK2-based desktops (like
>   Gnome).
>
> There are other ideas and scripts in
>   the discussion on this topic at Ubuntu
>   Brainstorm: [Idea #1744: GNOME themes
>   should affect Qt
>   themes](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/1744/),
>   and more of them in this discussion
>   [Idea #1714: GNOME QT
>   integration](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/1714/)
>   (and the numerous duplicate ideas
>   gathered under this question).
>
> One of the noteworthy attempts is
>   [**UniformUI**](http://andrealazzarotto.com/2009/06/14/uniformui-is-the-definitive-way-to-integrate-qt-and-kde-apps-in-the-gnome-desktop/),
>   which attempts to automate
>   configuration of Qt settings to match
>   the current Gtk+ style, partially
>   using
>   [**QtCurve**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QtCurve)
>   and
>   [**QGtkStyle**](http://labs.trolltech.com/page/Projects/Styles/GtkStyle)
>   to achieve this.

Fourth google result for "skin qt to match gtk"

Comment: It looks like `qgtkstyle` isn't available anymore on the link you provided. And as i searched for it, i couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: @71GA See this: http://code.google.com/p/qgtkstyle/

Answer (score 0):

This does the job, in Qt 5 and Gtk+ 3:

```
export QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE=gtk
```