# When I install Xubuntu 12.04, the Qt-applications font is horrible

Tags: fonts, skype, vlc, qt

What is the proper way to set up fonts in Skype, VLC, and so on?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/questions/22316/how-can-i-theme-my-qt-app-to-resemble-one-written-in-gtk

Comment: Possibly not - last time I looked in 12.04 Xubuntu that tool didn't work, just downloading it (slowly) to check again.

Comment: VLC is taking font settings as other apps are - no need for the tool here for that. @sergey - can you update question with themes/fonts you are using and perhaps try the qtconfig tool in the answer above

Comment: skype looks fine too

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem.  This is to help with the Ask Ubuntu Clean Up. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Comment: As @Seth mentioned 4+ years ago this question is abandoned and unanswered. Further 12.04 is EOL and OP hasn't signed on in 5+ years to respond to comments. As such VTC as `not reproducible`.