# Eagle CAD - GTK look

Tags: gtk, cad

I am an Archlinux (former Ubuntu) user and am writing here to ask how is the GTK (adwaita) look for application "Eagle CAD" achieved in Gnome Ubuntu remix or in normal Ubuntu. I can't seem to find any topic on how to do it on any of the distributions...

Comment: A screenshot would be perfect in this question...

Answer (score 1):

You should first find in what languages eaglecad is made of.

It's made in C++ and QT. ([SourceForge page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/eaglecad/))

So to sum up you try to apply a GTK theme to a QT User Interface.

Here is how to achieve this : [How can I theme my Qt app to resemble one written in Gtk?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22316/how-can-i-theme-my-qt-app-to-resemble-one-written-in-gtk)