# Calibre is not using GTK+ theme

Tags: themes, 15.04, calibre

I installed calibre from their site, not the packaged version, because it lags behind. It's working fine, but is using a different theme (plastic I guess) instead of my current theme (numix). Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: did you try to switch the themes to see if it take affect on the app? it might be that random themes cannot cover everything. For example as I recall I've never had issues with Mediterranean-theme, if it were qt or gtk etc.

Comment: I tried, but it wasn't working. I meanwhile switched back to the bundled version. It isn't as old as the one bundled in 14.04 and is working fine for now, including the theme. I think the calibre installer deploys it's dependencies in /opt/calibre/lib and that Qt library fails to find the theme settings.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to write more, but it's already explained here:
[How can I theme my Qt app to resemble one written in Gtk?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22316/how-can-i-theme-my-qt-app-to-resemble-one-written-in-gtk)

This little tool will allow you to switch to your selected gtk+ theme.

Comment: My guess is, that the "manual" install of calibre is either statically linked with Qt5 or looks for the theme in some other place, because this tool had no effect on it.